# Refresh animation not displaying when reloading tableview | Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I cannot seem to figure out why the loading animation stop appearing after I leave and come back to the `UITableViewController` the following is what I am seeing once I come back - the pull-down gesture still executes the reload code and refreshes the `UITableView`, just the animation is not showing.

**What I am seeing:**

[image]

**What I am doing:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemGroupedBackground
    edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
}
    
    
@objc func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    self.fetchJSON()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

**Setup in Storyboards:**

[image]

Is there something I am doing incorrect that would prevent the loader from appearing? To clarify it is showing on initial load, but then fails to appear when return

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your refresh control from the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() }
```